# Is there a knife, that can be legally carried in both NJ and NY?

Tags: new-jersey, weapons, new-york-city

I live in NJ, but work in NYC, and would like to find a knife, that can be legally carried in both locales.

[NYC seems to ban all folding knives](https://www.villagevoice.com/2014/10/10/so-what-knives-are-legal-in-new-york-city-anyway-the-answer-might-surprise-you/), while allowing any fixed-blades under 4" long.

NJ *appears to be* the opposite -- folding ones may be Ok, but fixed-blade require vague justifications like "explainable lawful purpose".

Is there anything suitable for both?

Comment: If you have an explainable lawful purpose, that shouldn't be an issue. If you don't have one, clearly you don't have good reason to carry the knife.

Comment: Carry your fixed blade knife in New York City but when you are in New Jersey, also carry around a sack full of cucumbers and slowly cut them into slices whenever you are out in public.

Comment: Self-defense is a good reason, but is not _considered by the legal system_ an explainable lawful purpose. There is also the rule, that "_rights no exercised are lost_" -- which is another good reason.

Comment: Both laws are attempting to curtail the use of knives as weapons, whether in "self-defence" or not.  If you want to carry a weapon in self-defence then you probably want to be carrying a gun, as the US Constitution makes it hard for either state to limit that.

Comment: The US Constitution does not distinguish firearms from any other weapons, but State (and Federal) governments ignore it... They just ignore it _differently_ and one may be able to get around the unconstitutional bans.

Answer (score 2):

> NYC seems to ban all folding knives, while allowing any fixed-blades under 4" long.

New York City does not ban all folding knives.  To qualify as a gravity knife, the knife must open by gravity or by centrifugal force.  The Village Voice published an [article](https://www.villagevoice.com/2014/10/07/how-a-50s-era-new-york-knife-law-has-landed-thousands-in-jail/) several years ago pointing out that nearly every folding pocket knife can be opened with enough force, but *nearly every* is not the same as *every.*

Regardless, the New York Times reports that [the gravity knife statute was repealed because it was found to be unconstitutionally vague](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/31/nyregion/ny-gravity-knife-law.html).  This was just over a year ago.  The Village Voice piece cited in the question is nearly five years out of date.

Comment: That's great news, but can you actually answer the question I asked? Preferably, with examples? Thank you!

Comment: @MikhailT. This isn't the place for product recommendations.

Comment: Identifying the generic name (like "Bowie"), or _shape_ of the product wouldn't be a _product_-recommendation...

Comment: @Mikhail: You are unlikely to receive a brand-specific answer to your question.  Per [help/on-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), Law.SE specifically disallows questions on specific legal matters; Law.SE is not intended to act as a substitute for legal advice.  If you want recommendations on what specific knives are legal for your situation, please consult a lawyer.

Comment: @MikhailT. Since folding knives are legal in New Jersey and, since last year, also in New York, that would seem to be the answer to your question: a folding knife.

Comment: Or a utility tool, which is more than a knife.